# I need to cd into directory with spaces `-bash: cd: too many arguments`

Tags: 16.04, cd-command

The error code is `-bash: cd: too many arguments`.

I am currently using Windows Subsystem running ubuntu 16.04

I tried using a backslash('\') and then the space(' ') , but it is still throwing me the same error.

Comment: Providing exact details of what directory you are trying to get into, plus the command you used would help us understand better. The backslash does work; so my guess is you weren't using it correctly or there is something else you're missing which you didn't tell us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also wrap your folder path in quotes. Try:

```
cd "new folder"
```