# Not able to run a program with a .sh script using Ubuntu WSL

Tags: command-line, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am new to Ubuntu. I installed Ubuntu on Windows 10 to run a program with Linux using ubuntu.

When I double-click on the Ubuntu app I get a shell (believe it is a WSL shell) with my `username@Desktop-IULTFHD-`.  Inside this shell, I get some info on root etc. for couple of lines and my `username@Desktop-IULTFHD:  $`

I type `cd` to change the directory to the location of the software.  Then I
run the `.sh` script.  However, it is either saying too many arguments or this command not found.

Can someone help to check:

1. Have I downloaded correct version of Ubuntu app.
2. If so, how to cd to get the path to direct that particular file and open the script.
3. DO I have the correct WSL

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the exact command(s) you typed and the complete error messages.

Comment: Also tell us what script you are trying to run and where you obtained it. Ubuntu over WSL cannot run all software. It can be very different from Ubuntu installed on bare metal. In particular, Ubuntu over WSL does not officially support GUI applications or desktop environments and does not have direct access to hardware.  So if you are trying to run something that needs to make changes to hardware or a script that requires a window, it's probably not going to run on WSL, at least not with some off-spec tweaking

Comment: The most likely issue is that you are trying to `cd` to a path that contains whitespace - see for example [I need to cd into directory with spaces `-bash: cd: too many arguments`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205757/i-need-to-cd-into-directory-with-spaces-bash-cd-too-many-arguments)

Answer (score 2):

You `cd` to the directory that contains the file, not the file itself. Alternatively, you can skip the cd command and just run the file by executing the full path of the file including the filename.

Example execution of a file named `script.sh` in your `~/Downloads` directory (assuming your user name is surendar):

```
/home/surendar/Downloads/script.sh
```

or to `cd`:

```
cd /home/surendar/Downloads
```

and then to run the example file named "script.sh"

```
./script.sh
```

You must prefix the script or file name with `./` if the file is in your current directory or it will not run.

Comment: Also, be careful, *nix based systems are case sensitive unlike Windows.